# Acumatica Mobile - Selector field not acting as a selector

Tags: acumatica

I'm adding a warehouse selector to the item detail on CR304500 and it's not behaving correctly.

I've added this customization to the screen:

```
update screen CR304500 {
    update container "DocumentDetails" {
        fieldsToShow = 5
        update layout "QuantityUOMRow" {
            add field "Warehouse" {
                placeAfter field "UOM"
                displayName = "Whse."
                selectorDisplayFormat = Key
                listDisplayFormat = Value
                listPriority = 96
                pickerType = Attached
                selector {
                    fieldsToShow = 2
                    add field "WarehouseID"
                    add field "Description"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the selector displays, it looks like it has a dropdown and it registers a click but nothing is displayed when it's clicked:

[image]

I can't figure out why this is. I'm new to selectors and tried a bunch of different options but wasn't able to get it to show the list of warehouses.

**Update:**
Per a suggestion, I added the PXSelector attribute to the SiteID field to make sure it was a selector. In order for it to work, I also needed to remove the PXForeignReference attribute from it and use a PXUIField attribute to make the name show as Warehouse instead of SiteID and it's still not working as a selector.

```
public class QuoteMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<QuoteMaint>
    {
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXForeignReferenceAttribute))]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INSite.siteID>),
            new Type[]
            {
                typeof(INSite.siteCD),
                typeof(INSite.descr)
            },
            SubstituteKey = typeof(INSite.siteCD))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Warehouse")]
        protected void CROpportunityProducts_SiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache) { }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the field resolves to a PXSegmentMask control instead of PXSelector control

Comment: It looks like you are on to something. @HuguesBeauséjour The field doesn't implement PXSelector so it looks like I have to add that with a cache attached event.

The current attributes are:
PXFormula
POSiteAvail
PXDefault
PXForeignReference

I think none of those are derived from PXSelector so I'll need to modify it to use the PXSelector and hopefully that solves it.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour I took your advice and applied a PXSelector that seems to work fine on the web browser UI, however, it still doesn't work correctly on the phone.. I'll update the question to include the code I added in the cache attached event so far.

Comment: > The field doesn't implement PXSelector so it looks like I have to add that with a cache attached event - Maybe it uses a custom attribute that derives from PXSegmentMask or PXSelector like [Site]. This could also be an issue.